# How to display data form PHP to previous HTML page

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap to make a HTML page which only contain a search form(let’s call it Page1), and I write a separate PHP file to handle the data from the form. Problem is how can I return the the result of the PHP file to the previous Page1, and display to below the search form? I mean I still want to display the data generate from PHP file in the previous bootstrap page and show it below the existing content.

Comment: HTML Pages are static so you can't make it  PHP instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same script to make additional output when you submit the form. Form will be submitted to itself and it will display desired/processed output according to submitted data below the initial form. It won't execute the php part if there is no submit button submitted. To give an idea how it would look:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="dataToPost">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="submit form">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
    {
        // process the post data and create output here
        print 'posted data is ' . $_POST['dataToPost'];
    }
?>
```

You can also fill the form controls with the submitted data, if you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: A little caution needs to be used with this approach. Refreshing the page will re-submit the form